# How to create events for toolbar?

Tags: c#-4.0, vsto, office-addins

I am trying to develop an addin for MS Office 2010. I am stuck in 
1)how to create events for toolbar?
2)How to initialize and deinitialize toolbar? 
3)How to initialize button event click handler and deinitialize
I am using Ribbon Visual Designer to develop the addin of my own. I am new to this.
I am also using C# 4.0 VSTO 2010.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the ribbon designer you should be able to double click on button, combobox or ribbon itself to create button click event and similarly for other controls.

You could also wire up the events in the Ribbon.cs codebehind directly in the Ribbon load event. when you type this it bring up the available events at application level in intellisense.

```
Globals.ThisAddin.Application.
```

Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608623.aspx

There is nothing like initialize and deinitialize toolbar in VSTO. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Kiru- are there any difference between the button click event and just the button click event? The ribbon event has "private void btnOption_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)" but the older command bar has  private void Options_Click(Core.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault).

Comment: @Kiru- Can I pass this "ref bool CancelDefault" to the ribbon button event only?

Comment: @Kiru- this is the custom parameter passed to the button click.

Comment: Why do you want to mix up with the command bar? What do you want to achieve with the parameter ref bool CancelDefault? I dont think you can change the signature of the builtin events.